# Handlng Paypal Payment API responses

Tags: php, paypal

I hope this is the right place to ask this question, but I cannot seem to find an answer in the documentation.

I'm working on implementing a payment solution with PHP and Paypal.

When processing a PAYPAL account payment I follow the steps required as described here:
[Accepting a Paypal Payment](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/integration/web/accept-paypal-payment/)

Working through the steps is not a problem. I get the expected results from a successful transaction.

My question is when it comes to handling errors/failed payments.

According to the documentation, the SALE state can be:

```
Possible values: completed, partially_refunded, pending, refunded, denied.
```

What would cause it to be PENDING? Further, does the SALE state being pending cause the PAYMENT state to be failed?

I'm trying to understand how these two states fit together and affect one another. The purpose is to handle the payments properly. Knowing when it is approved/denied so I can handle it accordingly.

Right now, my test code is as follows:

```
$response = executePaypalPayment($token, $payer_id, $payment_id);

    //Get the state of the payment
    $payment_state = $response->state;

    //Get the state of the sale
    $sale_state = $response->transactions[0]->related_resources[0]->sale->state;

    if($payment_state == "approved" && $sale_state == "completed"){
        //Everything was successful
        $message = 'Your order was placed successfully! A confirmation email has been sent to the email address provided.';
        displayOrderScreenMessage($message);

    } else {
        //Something went wrong
        if($payment_state !== "approved"){
            //payment failed
            $message = "Unable to process payment. Please try again.";
            displayOrderScreenMessage($message, true, true);
        }

    }
```

The problem is, I don't know how to tell for sure what the status of the payment is. Any help is appreciated. Thanks!